# VueJS1 dynamic $parent.$parent.function length

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to use a parent function in several nested child components

```
{{ $parent.$parent.testFunction('foo', 'bar') }}
```

This one is working, but every time I'm changing levels in the nest, I have to change the call, like:

```
{{ $parent.testFunction('foo', 'bar') }}
```

Is there a way to fix that?
The parent is not a $root level element, so that won't work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to use events for this, that way you can dispatch up the parent tree and then handle it as it arrives.

that way it wouldn't matter where your child and parent exist in the system.

```
events: {
    "testFunction": function(foo, bar) {
        // Do Foobar
        return true; // Stops the event from going further
                     // return nothing to have it continue up the chain
    }
}
```

then in your component just run

```
this.$dispatch("testFunction", "Foo", "bar");
```

Comment: `$dispatch` no longer exists in Vue 2.

Comment: @BillCriswell The question specified VueJS 1

Comment: Though, it seems OP is using these methods in templates, so not sure events would help that much? I'm thinking they should just be importing the method into any component that needs it. (They should actually be filters in my opinion).

Comment: That would depend on if the function being called requires the parent's state or not. a universal function like that would either need to pass state or not use state.

Comment: I had to modify it a bit, but `this.$dispatch("testFunction", ["Foo", "bar"]);` solved it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would be importing `testFunction` into any component that needs to use it personally.

```
var doFoo = function () {
  console.log('foo')
}

// Component A
{
  methods: {
    doFoo: doFoo,
  }
}

// Component B
{
  methods: {
    doFoo: doFoo,
  }
}
```

Though, I think you want to actually be using filters here.

Comment: If you were going for that design I'd put it into a mixin that way it can be distributed to the components that need it.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer it to be more explicit. If I needed to group a bunch of things I'd consider a mixin for the approach.